# returning the index of element in list C++

Tags: c++, list

It seems like very common question, but they are all asked in **python**. I would like to return index of the searched element in a list **!not STL!**

My function

```
void checkNode(LinkedList* head, int v)
{
LinkedList* p = head;
while (p != NULL) {
    if (p->data == v) {
        cout << ; // here should be answer i suppose
    }
    else {
        cout << -1;
    }

    p = p->next;
  }

}
```

Comment: Just count how many times the loop runs?

Comment: Note that this function cannot return anything. The return type is `void`. Consider something more like `int checkNode(LinkedList* head, int v)` and the later `return count;` in place of `cout << ;` and `return -1;` in place of `cout << -1;`. Not this doesn't tell you how to count, but if you can't count, you have  long way to go before you should consider taking up programming.

Comment: @SzymonSokołowski Please clarify, do you want to _return_ the result (as in the title) or only _print_ it (as your code suggests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare i, and increment the count as you traverse the list:

```
void checkNode(LinkedList* head, int v)
{
  LinkedList* p = head;
  int i=0; // Declare i
  while (p != NULL) {
    if (p->data == v) {
        cout << i; // output i
        return;
    }
    ++i; // Increment index counter
    p = p->next;
  }
  // we've searched through the entire list
  cout << -1; // not found
}
```

In case you actually want to return the index as you've stated and not as the code suggests. It would look like this:

```
int checkNode(LinkedList* head, int v)
{
  LinkedList* p = head;
  int i=0; // Declare i
  while (p != NULL) {
    if (p->data == v) { 
        return i;
    }
    ++i; // Increment index counter
    p = p->next;
  }
  // we've searched through the entire list
  return -1; // not found
}
```

Comment: There is no context in the name `i`. Prefer a meaningful identifier like `count`.